# Vowpal Wabbit - Slates (Combinatorial Bandit) with semi feedback

Tags: python, machine-learning, reinforcement-learning, recommendation-engine, vowpalwabbit

We are evaluating to use Vowpal Wabbit for our recommender system. We want to show different image (combinatorial) and see with which the user interacts.

Going through the documentation, Vowpal Wabbit supports with Slates the combinatorial setup. For the reward it is stated that:

> A single, global, reward is produced that signals the outcome of an entire slate of decisions. There’s a linearity assumption on the impact of each action on the observed reward.

I.e. the semi-feedback we need is not supported.

**Our question:** Is there a way to work with semi-feedback and Slits Vowpal Wabbit?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Let me confirm about semi-feedback: do you mean that you want to assign feedback only on specific slots (but not on the whole response)?
If so, then the short answer is no. Although there is conditional contextual bandits support: https://github.com/mritunjaysharma394/vowpal-wiki/blob/master/Conditional-Contextual-Bandit.md
You can reward only specific slots there, but the difference with the slates is that actions got chosen from the same pool - not sure how applicable it is for your scenario.